# Запятая после "хотя" в начале предложения.

Tags: пунктуация

"Если, я полагаю:"

Нужна ли?

Comment: Нельзя так усекать предложение, если хотите услышать правильный ответ

Answer (score 2):

Если "я полагаю" - вводное предложение, то запятая нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Так, как Вы задали вопрос, ответить однозначно невозможно.